# Color picker not working on Google Chrome web dev tools

Tags: google-chrome

[image]I've seen this video:

https://samrueby.com/2014/10/10/did-you-know-chrome-has-its-own-color-picker/

But when I click on the CSS color, all I can do is change the color, no pop up appears like in the video.

Is there a setting I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant to type "My color picker **not** working..." in the title.

The color picker is displayed when clicking on the **colored preview square**, instead of clicking the RGB values itself.

Comment: Not working either, I'm cicking on the small square box.

Comment: May have something to do with ShaderCache. Test by installing Google Chrome in another user account (without elevating the installer). Update graphics drivers if applicable. Lastly enable Google Chrome logging to catch any errors to a log file. https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone has the same problem I did, as of `v65.0.3325.181` (and probably earlier versions) the color picker only works on the tab you have the inspector opened for. If you need to pick a color from one tab to another, open up an inspector on that tab and pick the color. Then, highlight the color string (it should be a hex string like `#123abc`) and copy it to the desired tab's inspector.

If that still doesn't work, then make sure the picker is enabled in the first place. When the color selector popup is open, the "eyedropper" icon should be highlighted blue if the picker is active.